# Minimal PHP code for blueimp jQuery file upload

Tags: php, jquery, blueimp

Blueimp file upload library works great https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ but it lacks documentation about server side of things. They have included ~1300 lines of php code (all in one file), and at least half of that is bloated with GD and Imagick picture processing. Since I want to integrate this lib in my php framework and I need a full control what happens with uploaded files, I'm kinda lost in these 1300 lines. Is there a minimum php available which would just receive the file and put it in a directory of my choice?

Source: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
PHP specifically: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php

Comment: Yay! Finally it's my turn to post it! Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask